# How to tell if BitmapFactory.decodeFile() worked?

Tags: android, bitmap

The documentation says if BitmapFactory.decodeFile (filename, options) can't be decoded, it will return null.  However, it *always* returns null if the flag inJustDecodeBounds is true.

In my simple test case, I pass in a bad file name: file doesn't exist.  The only indication I can see that it failed is it sets options with outHeight and outWidth = 0.

A couple things I can do:

- test that the file exists before calling decodeFile()
- look at outHeight and outWidth

Aside from that, is there a correct way to check if decodeFile() worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're passing an instance of `BitmapFactory.Options` as second parameter. In that case, if the file does not exist, the options param is not updated. That's why you will have outWidth and outHeight = 0

Comment: Yes, that is true - i'm using Options.  Is that the right way to tell it couldn't decode the file?

Comment: if the decodeFile fails for any reason, the option is not updated an no exception is thrown. you should first check is the file exists and is accessible. something like: `File file = new File(path); file.exists() && file.canRead();`

Comment: What if it fails for some other reason besides bad file access.

Comment: There are many reasons why the decodeFile can fail, not just file not found or not accessible, maybe it's not a valid image file. That method just silently fails if the file cannot be decoded correctly. If you receive an outWidth and outHeight = 0 then you can assume the file cannot be opened for some reason.

Comment: So that's the best?  Just check for width and height = 0?  Pretty lame.

Comment: it's actually almost the same check you would do if you're trying to decode the file into a Bitmap (with no inJustDecodeBounds) . if the result is null then. for some reasons, the image could not be decoded.